# .Equals or == return false, always

Tags: c#, csv, datatable

here is my problem.

I have 2 datatables filed with the exact same content, but i don't get why, when i compare their columns neither `==` nor `.Equals` can return true.

```
public void btn_Source_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        FichierSource.OuvertureSource();
        FichierSource.OuvertureBanque(comboBox1);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn colonne in FichierSource.DTSource.Columns)
        {
            if (colonne == FichierSource.DTBanque.Columns[i]) 
                MessageBox.Show("Same");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Not the same");
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Both of the datatable are field with 2 different `CSV` but both `CSV` have this content : 

`Nom|Prenom|Date|numero
Jack|Jared|17.04.17|1626010548999
Daphne|Orli|08.02.18|1660101461799
Dphne|Thane|04.06.18|1635062807599
Odessa|Gannon|08.02.18|1626032546899
Charles|Jena|22.11.16|1626040845399`

I red a lot of same problems and **i thought i** understood the difference between == and .Equals but neither of those 2 return true, why ?

EDIT : 
here is a screenshot with both variable's value [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMknW.jpg)

Comment: Because both are different instances. It would work for string literals or integers etc because the operator is overloaded for those objects. For `DataColumn`, only if the instance is same it would return true. You would have to write a method to comapre the 2 objects

Comment: are you sure you understand what == and/or Equals do on object instances?

Comment: read up on how equals works first

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You don't compare the content of the `DataTables` but their `DataColumns`(which have a name and a type among other properties).
2. If you use `==` you only compare references(you have to overload the `==` operator to compare by value which f.e. [`System.String` does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality(v=vs.110).aspx))
3. `Equals` wouldn't help either because `DataColumn` doesn't override it. So [`Object.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) is used which just compares references(similar to `==`). Since those are are different `DataColumn` instances(same names but belong to different tables) both, `Equals` and `==`, return `false`

---

If you want to compare all fields of one `DataRow` with all fields of another `DataRow` you can use [`DataRowComparerer.Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907955(v=vs.110).aspx) and you have to loop the rows instead of the columns:

```
var rowFieldComparer = DataRowComparer.Default;
for(int i = 0; i < FichierSource.DTSource.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (rowFieldComparer.Equals(FichierSource.DTSource.Rows[i], FichierSource.DTBanque.Rows[i]))
        MessageBox.Show("Same");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Not the same");
}
```

Comment: Ok i got it, i thought i understood ==/.equals. 

thanks dude.

Comment: @FistiPaul: You're welcome. Note that i have edited my answer little bit. Have a look

Answer (score 0):

Both object are different instances. You should check primitive properties of them or write method to compare 2 objects.